# How can I draw a waveform efficiently

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display the waveform of an audio file. I would like the waveform to be drawn progressively as ffmpeg processes the file, as opposed to all at once after it's done. While I have achieved this effect, it's REALLY slow; like painfully slow. Its starts out really fast, but the speed degrades to the point of taking minutes to draw a sample.

I feel there has to be a way to do this more efficiently, as there is a program I use that does it, I just don't know how. The other program can take in >10 hours of audio and progressively display the waveform with no speed degradation. I have set ffmpeg to process the file at 500 samples/sec, but the other program samples at 1000/sec and it still runs faster than what I wrote. The other program's waveform display only takes about 120MB of RAM with a 10 hour file, where mine takes 1.5GB with a 10 minute file.

I'm fairly certain the slowness is caused by all the UI updates and the RAM usage is from all the rectangle objects being created. When I disable drawing the waveform, the async stream completes pretty fast; less than 1 min for a 10 hour file.

This is the only way I could think to accomplish what I want. I would welcome any help to improve what I wrote or any suggestions for an all together different way to accomplish it.

As a side note, this isn't all I want to display. I will eventually want to add a background grid to help judge time, and draggable line annotations to mark specific places in the waveform.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="AudioDisplayItemsControl"
              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              Height="100"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type poco:Sample}">
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}"
                       Height="{Binding Height}"
                       Fill="ForestGreen"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Black"
                    Width="500"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private string _audioFilePath;
public string AudioFilePath
{
    get => _audioFilePath;
    set
    {
        if (_audioFilePath != value)
        {
            _audioFilePath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<IShape> _samples;
public ObservableCollection<IShape> Samples
{
    get => _samples;
    set
    {
        if (_samples != value)
        {
            _samples = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

//Eventhandler that starts this whole process
private async void GetGetWaveform_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).IsEnabled = false;
    await GetWaveformClickAsync();
    ((Button)sender).IsEnabled = true;
}


private async Task GetWaveformClickAsync()
{
    Samples.Clear();
    double left = 0;
    double width = .01;
    double top = 0;
    double height = 0;
    await foreach (var sample in FFmpeg.GetAudioWaveform(AudioFilePath).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        // Map {-32,768, 32,767} (pcm_16le) to {-50, 50} (height of sample display)
        // I don't this this mapping is correct, but that's not important right now 
        height = ((sample + 32768) * 100 / 65535) - 50;

        // "0" pcm values are not drawn in order to save on UI updates,
        // but draw position is still advanced
        if (height==0)
        {
            left += width;
            continue;
        }
        // Positive pcm values stretch "height" above the canvas center line
        if (height > 0)
        top = 50 - height;
        // Negative pcm values stretch "height" below the centerline
        else
        {
            top = 50;
            height = -height;
        }

        Samples.Add(new Sample
        {
            Height = height,
            Width = width,
            Top = top,
            Left = left,
            ZIndex = 1
            });
        left += width;
    }
}
```

**Classes used to define a sample**

```cs
public interface IShape
{
    double Top { get; set; }
    double Left { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Shape : IShape
{
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public int ZIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Sample : Shape
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

**FFMpeg.cs**

```cs
public static class FFmpeg
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<short> GetAudioWaveform(string filename)
    {
        var args = GetFFmpegArgs(FFmpegTasks.GetWaveform, filename);

        await foreach (var sample in RunFFmpegAsyncStream(args))
        {
            yield return sample;
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Streams raw results of running ffmpeg.exe with given arguments string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">CLI argument string used for ffmpeg.exe</param>
    private static async IAsyncEnumerable<short> RunFFmpegAsyncStream(string args)
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"External\ffmpeg\bin\x64\ffmpeg.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            var buffer = new byte[2];
            while (true)
            {
                // Asynchronously read a pcm16_le value from ffmpeg.exe output
                var r = await process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 2);

                if (r == 0)
                break;

                yield return BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

`FFmpegTasks` is just an enum.
`GetFFmpegArgs` uses a switch argument on `FFmpegTasks` to return the appropriate CLI arguments for ffmpeg.exe.

I tried using the following class instead of the standard `ObservableCollection` because I was hoping that less UI updates would speed things up, but it actually made drawing the waveform slower.

**RangeObservableCollection.cs**

```cs
public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = true;

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your are plotting too much data. You should do a live plot, where you plot only new data to fill the viewport and not the complete set e.g., only plot a set of the last 1000 data values. Remove an old item, then add a new item. Implement the source collection as queue (or stack or ring buffer). If this still doesn't help you need to implement virtualization for the `Canvas` panel.

Comment: The solution is to only render the visible data and discard the data that is out of the viewport's bounds.

Comment: You're going to get a lot of rectangles there. Even if each is small by itself it adds up pretty quick. If you make that a listbox then you could use UI virtualisation. Assuming that is a viable option. If you need everything then you need a different technique. Never tried it to compare but I heard writeablebitmap is the thing to use for very dynamic lines like for sound waves. You're writing lines or whatever in a picture but rebuilding even quite a large picture is very fast. Hypsometric calculations and writeablebitmap for 1155 x 805 in our map took 20 something milliseconds iirc.

Comment: @BionicCode Unfortunately, I want to be able to display the whole waveform, possibly 10 hrs worth, at a time; I don't think the queue/stack idea will help. I thought about only showing more intermittent data points when the display is zoomed out to show the while waveform, and adding more as it starts to zoom in. I would still have to store them all, and 25 million shorts is still going to be a memory hog. Ill look into this virtualization; its something I am unfamiliar with. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @Andy Ill look into the writeablebitmap as well, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You have to think different here. The view can only display a fixed number of data points at a time. This number depends on the visible area, the viewport. let's assume you have a graph of 20 million data points, but only 200,000 will fit into the viewport. We know that a count of _x_ items will start to slow down your application, because of the rendering time increases beyond a tolerable threshold. This where the virtualization kicks in: to improve rendering time and therefore improve responsiveness, you only display the necessary i.e. visible 200,000 items.

Comment: Here is where the ring buffer comes into play: you add 200,000 items to the ring buffer. When the user scrolls to the right to view a different section of the graph you remove _n_ items from the beginning and add _n_ new items to the end. The buffer will always contain 200,000 items. That was the idea. This will give you back the responsive UI. You may search the web for a virtualizing canvas if you don't want to implement one yourself. Then replace the default `Canvas` with this.

Comment: I set up a crude virtualization and it sped things up, but was still slow because of the number of rectangles needed to get the detail i want in the waveform. I tried a writable bitmap with on display width's worth of samples. This drew VERY fast. Now I just have to put the two together. I have to rework some of my code to make it work. It will take me a git but once it works, I'll post the code as an answer to this question so others can see at least one way to make it work.

Comment: Yes, building a writeablebitmap is very fast and way quicker than datatemplating rectangles. I've only used the approach for static displays though. I would probably work with a 2d array and translate that. This is how the hypsometric code I have works. My unknowns are memory useage and overheads associated with redrawing the entire picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is all the code that is involved with drawing my waveform. I probably added a little more than necessary, but there is it. I was hoping to draw the waveform as it was processed, but gave up on that idea... for now. I hope this helps someone out there, because it took me 2 weeks in all to get this worked out. Comments are welcome.

Just as an FYI, on my pc it takes about 35 seconds to process a ~10hr m4b file and <2ms to display the image.

Also, it assumes a little-endian system. I put no checks in for big-endian systems, as I am not on one. If you are, the `Buffer.BlockCopy` will need some attention.

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```xml
<Border Background="Black"
        Height="100"
        Width="720"
        BorderThickness="0">
    <Image x:Name="WaveformImg" Source="{Binding Waveform, Mode=OneWay}"
    Height="100"
    Width="{Binding ImageWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    Stretch="Fill" />
</Border>

<Button Content="Get Waveform"
        Padding="5 0"
        Margin="5 0"
        Click="GetGetWaveform_Click" />
```

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void GetGetWaveform_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    ((Button)sender).IsEnabled = false;
    await ProcessAudiofile();
    await GetWaveformClickAsync(0, AudioData!.TotalSamples - 1);
    ((Button)sender).IsEnabled = true;
}

private async Task ProcessAudiofile ()
{
    var milliseconds = FFmpeg.GetAudioDurationSeconds(AudioFilePath);
    AudioData = new AudioData(await milliseconds, FFmpeg.SampleRate, new Progress<ProgressStatus>(ReportProgress));

    await AudioData.ProcessStream(FFmpeg.GetAudioWaveform(AudioFilePath)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private const int _IMAGE_WIDTH = 720;
private async Task GetWaveformClickAsync (int min, int max)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    int color_ForestGreen = 0xFF << 24 | 0x22 << 16 | 0x8c << 8 | 0x22 << 0; //

    Waveform = new WriteableBitmap(_IMAGE_WIDTH, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

    int col = 0;
    int currSample = 0;
    int row;
    var sampleTop = 0;
    var sampleBottom = 0;
    var sampleHeight = 0;

    //I thought this would draw the wave form line by line but it blocks the UI and draws the whole waveform at once
    foreach (var sample in AudioData.GetSamples(_IMAGE_WIDTH, min, max))
    {
        sampleBottom = 50 + (int)(sample.min * (double)50 / short.MinValue);
        sampleTop = 50 - (int)(sample.max * (double)50 / short.MaxValue);
        sampleHeight = sampleBottom - sampleTop;

        try
        {
            Waveform.Lock();

            DrawLine(col, sampleTop, sampleHeight, color_ForestGreen);

            col++;
        }
        finally
        {
            Waveform.Unlock();
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Image Creation: {sw.Elapsed}");
}


private void DrawLine (int column, int top, int height, int color)
{
    unsafe
    {

        IntPtr pBackBuffer = Waveform.BackBuffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            pBackBuffer = Waveform.BackBuffer;                    // Backbuffer start address
            pBackBuffer += (top + i) * Waveform.BackBufferStride; // Move to address or desired row
            pBackBuffer += column * 4;                            // Move to address of desired column

            *((int*)pBackBuffer) = color;
        }

    }

    try
    {
        Waveform.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(column, top, 1, height));
    }
    catch (Exception) { } // I know this isn't a good way to deal with exceptions, but its what i did.
}
```

**AudioData.cs**

```cs
public class AudioData
    {
        private List<short> _amp;           // pcm_s16le amplitude values
        private int _expectedTotalSamples;  // Number of samples expected to be returned by FFMpeg
        private int _totalSamplesRead;      // Current total number of samples read from the file

        private IProgress<ProgressStatus>? _progressIndicator;  // Communicates progress to the progress bar
        private ProgressStatus _progressStatus;                 // Progress status to be passed to progress bar

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of samples obtained from the audio file
        /// </summary>
        public int TotalSamples
        {
            get => _amp.Count;
        }   

        /// <summary>
        /// Length of audio file in seconds
        /// </summary>
        public double Duration
        {
            get => _duration;
            private set
            {
                _duration = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
            }
        }
        private double _duration;

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of data points per second of audio
        /// </summary>
        public int SampleRate
        {
            get => _sampleRate;
            private set
            {
                _sampleRate = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
            }
        }
        private int _sampleRate;

        /// <summary>Update the window's size.</summary>
        /// <param name = "duration" > How long the audio file is in milliseconds.</param>
        /// <param name = "sampleRate" > Number of times per second to sample the audio file</param>
        /// <param name = "progressIndicator" >Used to report progress back to a progress bar</param>
        public AudioData (double duration, int sampleRate, IProgress<ProgressStatus>? progressIndicator = null)
        {
            Duration = duration;
            SampleRate = sampleRate;
            _progressIndicator = progressIndicator;

            _expectedTotalSamples = (int)Math.Ceiling(Duration * SampleRate);

            _amp = new List<short>();
            _progressStatus = new ProgressStatus();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get values from an async pcm_s16le stream from FFMpeg
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "sampleStream" >FFMpeg samples stream</param>
        public async Task ProcessStream (IAsyncEnumerable<(int read, short[] samples)> sampleStream)
        {
            _totalSamplesRead = 0;

            _progressStatus = new ProgressStatus
            {
                Label = "Started",
            };

            await foreach ((int read, short[] samples) in sampleStream)
            {
                _totalSamplesRead += read;
                _amp.AddRange(samples[..read]);     // Only add the number of samples that where read this iteration
                
                UpdateProgress();
            }

            Duration = _amp.Count() / SampleRate;   // update duration to the correct value; incase duration reported by FFMpeg was wrong
            UpdateProgress(true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Report progress back to the UI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="finished">Is FFmpeg done processing the file</param>
        private void UpdateProgress (bool finished = false)
        {
            int percent = (int)(100 * (double)_totalSamplesRead / _expectedTotalSamples);

            // Calculate progress update interval; once every 1%
            if (percent == _progressStatus.Value)
                return;

            // update progress status bar object
            if (finished)
            {
                _progressStatus.Label = "Done";
                _progressStatus.Value = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                _progressStatus.Label = $"Running ({_totalSamplesRead} / {_expectedTotalSamples})";
                _progressStatus.Value = percent;
            }


            _progressIndicator?.Report(_progressStatus);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get evenly spaced sample subsets of the entire audio file samples
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">Number of samples to be returned</param>
        /// <returns>An IEnumerable tuple containg the minimum and maximum amplitudes of a range of samples</returns>
        public IEnumerable<(short min, short max)> GetSamples (int count)
        {
            foreach (var sample in GetSamples(count, 0, -_amp.Count - 1))
                yield return sample;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get evenly spaced sample subsets of a section of the audio file samples
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">number of data points to return</param>
        /// <param name="min">inclusive starting index</param>
        /// <param name="max">inclusive ending index</param>
        /// <returns>An IEnumerable tuple containing the minimum and maximum amplitudes of a range of samples</returns>
        public IEnumerable<(short min, short max)> GetSamples (int count, int min, int max)
        {
            // Protect from out of range exception
            max = max >= _amp.Count ? _amp.Count - 1 : max;
            max = max < 1 ? 1 : max;
            min = min >= _amp.Count - 1 ? _amp.Count - 2 : min;
            min = min < 0 ? 0 : min;

            
            double sampleSize = (max - min) / (double)count;  // Number of samples to inspect for return value
            short rMin;         // Minimum return value
            short rMax;         // Maximum return value
            int ssOffset;
            int ssLength;
            for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
            {
                // Calculate offset; no account for min
                ssOffset = (int)(n * sampleSize);

                // Determine how many samples to get, with a minimum of 1
                ssLength = sampleSize <= 1 ? 1 : (int)((n + 1) * sampleSize) - ssOffset;
                
                //shift offset to account for min
                ssOffset += min;   
                
                // Double check that ssLength wont take us out of bounds
                ssLength = ssOffset + ssLength >= _amp.Count ? _amp.Count - ssOffset : ssLength;

                // Get the minimum and maximum amplitudes in this sample range
                rMin = _amp.GetRange(ssOffset, ssLength).Min();
                rMax = _amp.GetRange(ssOffset, ssLength).Max();

                // In case this sample range has no (-) values, make the lowest one zero. This makes the rendered waveform look better.
                rMin = rMin > 0 ? (short)0 : rMin;
                rMax = rMax < 0 ? (short)0 : rMax;

                yield return (rMin, rMax);
            }
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class ProgressStatus
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

**FFMpeg.cs**

```cs
private const int _BUFER_READ_SIZE = 500;  // Number of bytes to read from process.StandardOutput.BaseStream. Must be a multiple of 2
public const int SampleRate = 1000;

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<(int, short[])> GetAudioWaveform (string filename)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = FFMpegStartInfo(FFmpegTasks.GetWaveform, filename);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        await Task.Delay(1000);         // Give process.StandardOutput a chance to build up values in BaseStream
        var bBuffer = new byte[_BUFER_READ_SIZE];    // BaseStream.ReadAsync buffer
        var sBuffer = new short[_BUFER_READ_SIZE / 2];    // Return value buffer; bBuffer.length
        int read = 1;  // ReadAsync returns 0 when BaseStream is empty
        while (true)
        {
            read = await process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadAsync(bBuffer, 0, _BUFER_READ_SIZE);

            if (read == 0)
                break;


            Buffer.BlockCopy(bBuffer, 0, sBuffer, 0, read);
            yield return (read / 2, sBuffer);
        }
    }
}

private static ProcessStartInfo FFMpegStartInfo (FFmpegTasks task, string inputFile1, string inputFile2 = "", string outputFile = "", bool overwriteOutput = true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFile1))
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(inputFile1), "Path to input file is null or empty");
    if (!File.Exists(inputFile1))
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"No file found at: {inputFile1}", nameof(inputFile1));

    var args = task switch
    {
        // TODO: Set appropriate sample rate
        // TODO: remove -t xx
        FFmpegTasks.GetWaveform => $@" -i ""{inputFile1}"" -ac 1 -filter:a aresample={SampleRate} -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -f data -",
        FFmpegTasks.DetectSilence => throw new NotImplementedException(),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
    };

    return new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = @"External\ffmpeg\bin\x64\ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    public enum FFmpegTasks
    {
        GetWaveform
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try drawing a [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.path?view=netcore-3.1) by hand. I use this to draw histograms of images in an application:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a histogram to a <see cref="PathGeometry"/>.
/// This is used by converters to draw a path.
/// It is easiest to use the default Canvas width and height and then use a ViewBox.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="histogram">The counts of each value.</param>
/// <param name="CanvasWidth">Width of the canvas</param>
/// <param name="CanvasHeight">Height of the canvas.</param>=
/// <returns>A path geometry. This value can be bound to a <see cref="Path"/>'s Data.</returns>
public static PathGeometry HistogramToPathGeometry(int[] histogram, double CanvasWidth = 100.0, double CanvasHeight = 100.0)
{
    double xscale = CanvasWidth / histogram.Length;
    double histMax = histogram.Max();

    double yscale = CanvasHeight / histMax;

    List<LineSegment> segments = new List<LineSegment>();
    for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
    {
        double X = i * xscale;
        double Y1 = histogram[i] * yscale;

        double Y = CanvasHeight - Y1;
        if (Y == double.PositiveInfinity) Y = CanvasHeight;
        segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(X, Y), true));
    }
    segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight), true));
    PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(new Point(0, CanvasHeight), segments, true);

    geometry.Figures = new PathFigureCollection
    {
        figure
    };
    return geometry;
}
```

Then have this in your Xaml:

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
    <Path Data="{Binding ConvertedPathGeometry}" />
</Canvas>
```

You could change this up so it handles the data as it is coming in. I'm not sure how well it would work with a lot of points, but you could only update the view after a handful of new points have come in. I've dealt with trying to draw many rectangles in a display and have the same issue you are running into.